# Data Inconsistency due to for loop and .map() from BACK4APP API

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, react-tsx

I am having issues in my data consistency due to the `for (const object of results) {}` in the [Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-ionic-6-and-back4app-cj54nx?file=/src/components/ExploreContainer.tsx:1303-1334) `line41` the Results are displayed as a single result after using `.map()` method however when i `console.log([toDoTasks]);` in `line79` All the results are displayed normally ,

***Note: Please Check the SandBox `console`***

1. My Question is there an alternative way to fetch for example        `const title: string = object.get("title");` the `props` for the `object`  here which would return all the results not just the single result  ?

```
import "./ExploreContainer.css";
import { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Parse = require("parse");

interface ContainerProps {}

const ExploreContainer: React.FC<ContainerProps> = () => {
  var [toDoTasks, setToDoTasks] = useState({
    objectId: "", //string
    title: "", //string
    description: "", //string
    task: "", //string
    isCompleted: Boolean(), //boolval
    createdAt: new Date(), //new Date()
    updatedAt: new Date() //new Date() to update the current time
  });

  //var query = new Parse.Query("ToDo");

  const readTasks = useCallback(async function (): Promise<Boolean> {
    // extend todo
    // Simple syntax to create a new subclass of Parse.Object.
    const ToDo: Parse.Object[] = Parse.Object.extend("ToDo");
    //parse query
    const parsequery: Parse.Query = new Parse.Query(ToDo);
    //const memoizedValue = useMemo(() =>  (""), [] );
    try {
      const results: Parse.Object[] = await parsequery.find();
      //ID MUST BE PARSED AND STRINGIFIED
      var resultsObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
      let id = resultsObj[0].objectId;
      //console.log(id);

      // alternative option
      //get by parameter
      //console.log(parsequery.equalTo('objectId', id));

      console.log(JSON.stringify(results));

      for (const object of results) {
        //Accessing the Parse Object attributes
        const title: string = object.get("title");
        const description: string = object.get("description");
        const task: string = object.get("task");
        const isCompleted: boolean = object.get("isCompleted");
        const createdAt: Date = object.get("createdAt");
        const updatedAt: Date = object.get("updatedAt");

        let resultsfix = {
          objectId: id, //string
          title: title, //string
          description: description, //string
          task: task, //string
          isCompleted: isCompleted, //boolval
          createdAt: createdAt, //new Date()
          updatedAt: updatedAt //new Date() to update the current time
        };
        setToDoTasks(resultsfix);
      }
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error has been found in getAllTasks()" + error);
      return false;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    readTasks();
  }, [readTasks]);

  return (
    <>
      {toDoTasks !== null &&
        toDoTasks !== undefined &&
        //ARRAY NEEDS TO BE ASSIGNED TO
        [toDoTasks].map((todo: any, item: any) => {
          //DISPLAY RESULTS HERE BUT IN GUI DISPLAYS ONLY SIGNLE RESULT
          console.log([toDoTasks]);
          console.log([todo?.title?.toLocaleLowerCase()]);
          return (
            <div key={todo + item}>
              <h5>{[todo?.title?.toLocaleUpperCase() || " "]}</h5>

              {[todo?.task?.toLocaleLowerCase() || " "]}

              <h5 className="ion-text-white">
                <strong>Description</strong>
              </h5>
              <em>{[todo?.description?.toLocaleLowerCase() || " "]}</em>

              <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>ObjectId</th>
                    <th>Done?</th>
                    <th>Created </th>
                    <th>Updated </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td> {JSON.stringify(todo?.objectId)}</td>
                    <td>
                      <p
                        className={
                          todo?.isCompleted === true
                            ? "todo_text-done"
                            : "todo_text"
                        }
                      >
                        {todo?.isCompleted?.toString()}
                      </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>{todo?.createdAt?.toDateString()}</td>
                    <td>{todo?.updatedAt?.toDateString()}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
};

export default ExploreContainer;
```

Comment: Should `toDoTasks` be an array? You have it as one object and just set that one object over and over replacing it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is how you're setting the state with a new object, as pointed out by @crashmstr in the comment.

I have changed how you render description text but now you can modify it if you want to.

you can see it in my sandbox as well [Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-ionic-6-and-back4app-forked-nqlu4o?file=/src/components/ExploreContainer.tsx:0-4001)

here is the modified code.

```
import "./ExploreContainer.css";
import { useCallback, useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Parse = require("parse");

interface ContainerProps {}

const ExploreContainer: React.FC<ContainerProps> = () => {
  var [toDoTasks, setToDoTasks] = useState([
    {
      objectId: "", //string
      title: "", //string
      description: "", //string
      task: "", //string
      isCompleted: Boolean(), //boolval
      createdAt: new Date(), //new Date()
      updatedAt: new Date() //new Date() to update the current time
    }
  ]);

  //var query = new Parse.Query("ToDo");

  const readTasks = useCallback(async function (): Promise<Boolean> {
    // extend todo
    // Simple syntax to create a new subclass of Parse.Object.
    const ToDo: Parse.Object[] = Parse.Object.extend("ToDo");
    //parse query
    const parsequery: Parse.Query = new Parse.Query(ToDo);
    //const memoizedValue = useMemo(() =>  (""), [] );
    try {
      const results: Parse.Object[] = await parsequery.find();
      //ID MUST BE PARSED AND STRINGIFIED
      var resultsObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
      let id = resultsObj[0].objectId;
      //console.log(id);

      // alternative option
      //get by parameter
      //console.log(parsequery.equalTo('objectId', id));

      console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
      const mappedData = [];
      for (const object of results) {
        //Accessing the Parse Object attributes
        const title: string = object.get("title");
        const description: string = object.get("description");
        const task: string = object.get("task");
        const isCompleted: boolean = object.get("isCompleted");
        const createdAt: Date = object.get("createdAt");
        const updatedAt: Date = object.get("updatedAt");

        let resultsfix = {
          objectId: id, //string
          title: title, //string
          description: description, //string
          task: task, //string
          isCompleted: isCompleted, //boolval
          createdAt: createdAt, //new Date()
          updatedAt: updatedAt //new Date() to update the current time
        };
        mappedData.push(resultsfix);
      }
      setToDoTasks(mappedData);
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error has been found in getAllTasks()" + error);
      return false;
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    readTasks();
  }, [readTasks]);

  return (
    <>
      {/* //ARRAY NEEDS TO BE ASSIGNED TO MAP OVER VALUES
            //DISPLAY RESULTS HERE BUT IN GUI DISPLAYS ONLY SIGNLE RESULT */}

      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ObjectId</th>
              <th>description </th>
              <th>Done?</th>
              <th>Created </th>
              <th>Updated </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {toDoTasks.map((todo: any, item: any) => {
              <h5>{[todo?.title?.toLocaleUpperCase() || " "]}</h5>;

              {
                [todo?.task?.toLocaleLowerCase() || " "];
              }

              return (
                <>
                  <tr>
                    <td> {JSON.stringify(todo?.objectId)}</td>
                    <td>
                      <em>{[todo?.description?.toLocaleLowerCase() || " "]}</em>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <p
                        className={
                          todo?.isCompleted === true
                            ? "todo_text-done"
                            : "todo_text"
                        }
                      >
                        {todo?.isCompleted?.toString()}
                      </p>
                    </td>
                    <td>{todo?.createdAt?.toDateString()}</td>
                    <td>{todo?.updatedAt?.toDateString()}</td>
                  </tr>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ExploreContainer;
```

Comment: Thank you @crashmstr @FaizanUlHaq Mate you guys  are life savers been stuck at this over a month now didn't know i passed the ```object``` in that way my intention was something else at all! good luck and peace to you guys